# Setting Location Based Column Defaults with SPServices

Tags: metadata

I know that setting location based column defaults is possible programatically using visual studio which isn't an option for me.

Is it possible using spservices or another jquery library?

Cheers,

Moonweazel

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks for the comment Tiago!  I didn't know that at all.  That page is created when you first setup the location based defaults.  What is very interesting is that any changes made to the page in SPD don't reflect in the browser.  I am going to have a go at editing that page via scripting to see if that somehow makes a difference.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Metadata Location-Based Defaults is a part of the [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.metadatadefaults%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

My guess is that this api is only available on the server side.

As for SPServices you can [ask them directly](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/566789), as you may already have.

You may find interesting that what actually happens when you setup columns defaults is that a file called `client_LocationBasedDefaults.html` is saved inside your library.

Perhaps you may want to try and tweak it yourself using client side script and see what happens.

```
<MetadataDefaults>
    <a href="/sites/mm/meetings/NANA-20140924-test">
        <DefaultValue FieldName="Meeting_Date">2014-09-24T03:48:40Z</DefaultValue>
    </a>
</MetadataDefaults>
```