# Sharepoint 2010 setting folder default metadata via Powershell

Tags: 2010, metadata

In a Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise site.
I've got a library containing documents pertaining to foreign countries.
So I have folders for Argentina, Chile, etc.. 
The list items have a text field called Country which I'm trying to set.

I don't want to go through all the folders and set the default Country field to the same as the containing folder, so I'm writing a Powershell script...

```
    $lib = $web.Lists["dguide"]
    $metadataDefaults = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults -ArgumentList $lib
    $Thisfolder = $web.GetFolder("dguide/$Foldername")
    $metadataDefaults.SetFieldDefault($Thisfolder,"Country", $Foldername)  

    $metadataDefaults.update()
    $Thisfolder.update()
    $lib.update()

    $folderDefaultValue = $metadataDefaults.GetFieldDefault($Thisfolder, "Country")
    "the value is now $folderDefaultValue"
```

Even though the value appears to change, it doesn't change in practice.
The folder gets a little green 'settings' gear suggesting customization, but the value is "" for country.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, nothing, eh?

Comment: try just updating $metadataDefaults. I don't think you need to update the folder or the library, which sometimes may cause undesired effects

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d214711b-571e-4039-9583-78a588be2f8c/folder-path-in-metadatadefaults-is-casesensitive?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) the folder path is case sensitive.

The poster OlegO states:

> For example if your folder is `/Shared Documents/Abc` and you use `/Shared Documents/abc` or `/shared documents/Abc` or `/SHARED DOCUMENTS/ABC` to execute `MetadataDefaults.SetFieldDefault method`.
>
> The `SetFieldDefault` method returns true, but your settings wouldn't be applied to folder.
>
> Additional problem if you get SPFolder from "wrong" url  `http://site/shared documents/abc` and then use SPFolder in `MetadataDefaults.SetFieldDefault`, your settings wouldn't be applied to folder, also.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to set the server relative path myself. Passing in the folder object didn't work but was passing back true.

It worked just fine when I set the full path as below,

```
$metadataDefaults.SetFieldDefault("/hr/EmployeeFiles/Mike/Administration", "DocumentCategory", $value)
```

I got a hint from [Setting Location Based Column Defaults with SPServices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114370/setting-location-based-column-defaults-with-spservices)

Going to work on calculating the path programmatically.